# Footer with centered text - image - text bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So at the moment i feel extremely stupid for this question, i want a footer with the following content horizontal(in this order): text - image - text

This works, but i want it centered and that wont happen on xs.

[This is my code (in a jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/92w2e5cp/4/)

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="copyright">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <p class="pull-right">
                    {{date('Y')}}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 ">
                <img src="{{asset('images/frontend/company-logo/icon/wedesignit_icon_v2018.svg')}}" alt="Wedesignit" style="height: 34px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p class="pull-left">@lang('site.tagline.company-name') <span class="hidden-xs">@lang('site.tagline.niche')</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone could help me out with this stupid thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem wasn't with my code or whatsoever, the guy that created the template changed the core off bootstrap and thats why the thing wont work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18865999)

Comment: Well it does since its my own question ?,

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
<div class="col-xs-2  text-center">
```

Answer (score 0):

It comes up to choosing the right proportions for your grid. As you propably know bootstrap grid consists of 12 columns, so you can center your image or any element for that matter by choosing the right col class. For example:

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
 <p class="pull-right">
   2018
 </p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">
 <img src="https://oneshoe.nl/sites/default/files/laravel-l-slant.png"  style="height: 34px;">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
 <p class="pull-left">Company does nice things</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I did already tried that but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Hello with this way it perfectly centered in the middle
https://jsfiddle.net/92w2e5cp/13/

```
<footer id="footer" class="dark-bg padding-top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="copyright">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <p class="pull-right">
                        2018
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="https://oneshoe.nl/sites/default/files/laravel-l-slant.png"  style="height: 34px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <p class="pull-left">Company does nice things</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</footer>
```

css

```
.row{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row div {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```